# query google spreadsheet with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google speadsheet that contains contact info. Currently I'm able to load the spreadsheet in and have a name filter but it loads the actual spreadsheet. What I'm looking for is to have label boxes(address, city, state, etc..) get filled depending on what name the users is searching for, looking similar to a business card and not a spreadsheet..

Comment: Which part would you need help with? the searching or the displaying? You can [make a User Interface for a spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp).

Comment: Hi PHil,

I've used this video so far to create a UI

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3deomYqHKgA

but I would like to know how to pull in record specific data. For instance, if I search for a name, I'd like to load in the address and contact info into labels so it looks more formal instead of just having a spreadsheet load.

Comment: Maybe you can post some code so I can get a better understanding of what you have so far. Thanks.

Comment: this is hat I currently have:
https://script.google.com/d/10MBN04bF6M98bVw1fIW4mnZpu1J-wf-8DnSZ6LlFW9CaqB6VbcmhGx5R/edit

Answer (score 1):

Something like that maybe ?

- [online app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxquizfGo85vdeaN7_qss2-LY--UxSLFFeF5ML5rXPWZfrX9oNt/exec)
- [code](https://script.google.com/d/1aL_y6ZqrfqrzhDZ4yzxM9Ax5hGi9KOHR0ltZ-7gVOTpQCDXV9zY3Ka_Y/edit) the source spreadsheet key is in the script (var key=...) just add *https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=* before this key and you get the url - please make a copy before changing anything, this ss is shared with edit rights to anybody with the link. (there is also an version of the script in the same ss that is partially in English ;-)
- screen capture below

[image]

All this coming from a spreadsheet like below :
[image]

Comment: this is perferct! but one big issue...can I get this in english?

Comment: :-)  since you have access to the script you can quite easily translate the few items that need to be translated... no really big deal...isn't it? I wrote it in french because that's my language,if you get stuck on some words I''be glad to help but Google translate will do it even better!

Comment: thanks Serge, Is the background data in a google spreadsheet? If so, can you send me the structure of what the spreadsheet looks like?

Comment: btw, I noticed that the script embedded in the spreadsheet is partially translated... I had the intention to do it but finally I  didn't because I probably didn't have good reasons to do so ;-)

Comment: I attempted to access the sheet with the URL + key, but it didn't seemed to be shared with 'anyone with link', at least not anymore.  Would love to have a look at the Sheet.  But, in any case, a very generous share of code!  Thank you!

Comment: Took a look removed myself from sharing, thanks.  It does say, however, that it's shared with link within INSAS.  Not with anyone on web. And thank you!